# Lightning Component Display Integer from Apex Class

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have created an Apex class which takes the opportunity Id and finds me the days between two today and future date, what i'm now struggling to do is display this within my lightning aura component.

Apex Class

```
public with sharing class DaysUntilShowController {

@AuraEnabled
public static Integer getShowDate(Id OpportunityId){
    system.debug(OpportunityId);

    BaseOpportunities opportunityController = Application.sobjectController.getBaseOpportunityController( new Set<Id> { opportunityId } );
    Opportunity oppRecord = (Opportunity)opportunityController.getRecord( opportunityId );
    system.debug(oppRecord);
    if (oppRecord.CXT_Master_Festival__c == NULL) {
        throw new Application.MissingRequiredValueException( 'Opportunity has no '+SObjectUtil.getFieldLabel(BaseOpportunities.describeResult,'CXT_Master_Festival__c')+' set.', oppRecord );
    }

    CXT_Festivals__c oppFestival = (CXT_Festivals__c)Application.dbController.getRecords( new Set<Id> { oppRecord.CXT_Master_Festival__c },
                        BaseFestivals.getQuerySelect()+' WHERE Id IN :recordIds' )[0];

    Date showDate = oppFestival.CXT_Start_Date__c;
    Date todaysDate = Date.today();

    Integer daysBetween = todaysDate.daysBetween(showDate);

    system.debug(daysBetween);
    return daysBetween;
    }
}
```

JS Controller

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getShowDate");
    action.setParams({ opportunityId : component.get("v.recordId") });

            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var returnValue = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set( "v.daysBetween", returnValue.daysBetween );

        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

handleOpportunityUpdated: function(component, event, helper) {
    var eventParams = event.getParams();
    if(eventParams.changeType === "CHANGED") {
        var reInit = component.get('c.doInit');
        $A.enqueueAction(reInit);
    }
}
})
```

Component

```
<aura:component controller="DaysUntilShowController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId"
            access="global" >

<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<aura:attribute name="thisFestival" type="CXT_Festivals__c" />
<aura:attribute name="thisOpportunity" type="Opportunity" /> 
<aura:attribute name="DaysBetween" type ="Integer"/>

<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
    fields="Id"
    targetFields="{!v.thisOpportunity}"/>

    <lightning:card variant="Narrow">
    <aura:set attribute="title">
        <div class="slds-media slds-media--center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
            <div class="slds-media__figure"><lightning:icon iconName="custom:custom11" class="m2020-icon-sponsorship_level" size="small"/></div>
            <div class="slds-media__body"><span class="slds-card__header-link">Days Left to Show</span></div>
        </div>
    </aura:set>
        <lightning:tile> 
            <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
            <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate">Days to Show:</dt>
                <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate">
                    {!v.daysBetween}
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </lightning:tile>

</lightning:card>
```

It just displays blank and i can't understand what i'm missing even though the system.debug displays a value in "daysBetween".

Comment: Also it's case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mostly everything right except that you are not setting the return value correctly. The format to set a value is `component.set("v.attributeName", value)` where it expects the name of the attribute and the value to be set. So in your `doInit()` function, where you are getting the response, you will need to set the attribute as below assuming you are getting successful response back.

```
if (state === "SUCCESS") {
    component.set( "v.daysBetween", response.getReturnValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your callback:

```
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        component.set( "v.daysBetween" ); --> Does nothing
        var returnValue = response.getReturnValue(); --> assigns the server response to an unused variable.

    }
});
```

You don't seem to actually be setting the attribute value based on the response from your apex class, you are simply calling set attribute to nothing and assigning the response to an unused variable `returnValue`

Additionally, this is not a lighting web component, it is a lightning aura component.

The documentation, [Handling Events with Client-Side Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_client_side_controller.htm) is pretty clear on how to set values based on a server response.

Comment: if you set the value to the variable before declaring it, it will be undefined and wont populate the integer in your markup

Comment: i think i realized my mistake,  i updated the these lines - var returnValue = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set( "v.daysBetween", returnValue.daysBetween );  this has fixed the undefined issue just need it to appear now on the aura component

Comment: var returnValue  should be returning the integer, since this is what you are telling your apex method to return, and you are assigning the server response to the variable

Comment: thats returning the value but on the component itself {!v.daysBetween } doesn't show the value 19 that the returnValue has found

Comment: `returnValue.daysBetween` wont work - `returnValue` should suffice

Comment: Just updated with Jayants code instead of calling that in the VAR 19 is now showing as expected

Comment: do you understand why your code wasn't working at least?

Comment: I think so i was trying to push it to a value that never existed/undefined  when the reutrnValue was all i actually needed

Comment: exactly  =), also make sure you declare your variables before trying to assign them to attributes.